# Label american current source correctly

Tags: labels, circuitikz

I am trying to put a label in the right of the american current source, but it doesn't want to go. I tried to use `l>=$4$A` instead of `i>=$4$A` but there is an error on that. I tried to use v instead of i but the polarization shows up. What would be the solution for that?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
        \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages, american currents, european resistors]
        \draw (0,0) 
        to[V, l=$50V$] (0,2)
        to[short, -*] (1.5,2)
        to[R, l=$5\Omega$] (3.5,2)
        to[R, l=$50\Omega$, -*] (3.5,0)         
        to[short] (0,0) (1.5,2)
        to[R, l=$40\Omega$, -*] (1.5,0) (5.5,2)     
        to[short] (7.5,2) (7.5,0)
        to[I, i>=$4$A] (7.5,2) (7.5, 0)
        to[short] (3.5,0) (5.5,2)
        to[R, l=$100\Omega$, -*] (5.5,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `to[I, i_>=$4$A] (7.5,2) (7.5, 0)`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
        \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages, american currents, european resistors]
        \draw (0,0)
        to[V, l=$50V$] (0,2)
        to[short, -*] (1.5,2)
        to[R, l=$5\Omega$] (3.5,2)
        to[R, l=$50\Omega$, -*] (3.5,0)
        to[short] (0,0) (1.5,2)
        to[R, l=$40\Omega$, -*] (1.5,0) (5.5,2)
        to[short] (7.5,2) (7.5,0)
        to[I, i_>=$4$A] (7.5,2) (7.5, 0)   %% Note _>= instead of >=
        to[short] (3.5,0) (5.5,2)
        to[R, l=$100\Omega$, -*] (5.5,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As of July 1, 2022, the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237468/200495), posted by *user11232*, does produce the intended results.

One has to use `to[I, l_=$4$A] (7.5,2) (7.5, 0)` instead of `to[I, i_>=$4$A] (7.5,2) (7.5, 0)`. `i>=` will show the current on the wire instead of beside the current source. The underscore after `l` will move the label to the right instead of the left, and the `>` after `l_` will not be required either.

The full code is:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages, american currents, european resistors]
    
        \draw (0,0) 
        to[V, l=$50V$, invert] (0,2)  % Note the 'invert' option
        to[short, -*] (1.5,2)
        to[R, l=$5\Omega$] (3.5,2)
        to[R, l=$50\Omega$, -*] (3.5,0)
        to[short] (0,0) (1.5,2)
        to[R, l=$40\Omega$, -*] (1.5,0) (5.5,2)
        to[short] (7.5,2) (7.5,0)
        to[I, l_=$4A$] (7.5,2) (7.5, 0)   % Note l_= instead of i_>= or i>=
        to[short] (3.5,0) (5.5,2)
        to[R, l=$100\Omega$, -*] (5.5,0);
    
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
```

Also, note the `invert` after the voltage source.

[image]

**Edit:**

As suggested by [@aoi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/173134/aoi) in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237464/label-american-current-source-correctly/649574#comment1618875_649574) to this answer, instead of using `invert` for each voltage source, one may use `RPvoltages` option:

```
usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
```

Comment: Rather than putting an `invert` in every voltage source needed like this, why not use the option `RPVoltages` (rising potential voltages)?

Comment: @aoi Thanks for the suggestion; added that to the answer.